# Multiple ListViews in single activity

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

So I need to have 3 dividers between lists, I have beginner, intermediate and advanced list and above each of that lists is a button which is not clickable or anything, it's just there to display some text.

But when I coded it it does not display right even though every list view is in seperate LinearLayout with exact amount of weight.

Here's XML Code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="hr.app.liftme.liftmehr.ListaProgramiBodybuilding"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_lista_programi_bodybuilding">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/buttonProgrami1"
        android:background="#2196f3"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="@string/programi_pocetnici"/>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:id="@+id/listaProgramiPocetnici">
    </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="#2196f3"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"

        android:id="@+id/buttonProgrami2"
        android:text="@string/programi_srednji"/>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:id="@+id/listaProgramiSrednji">
    </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="#2196f3"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:id="@+id/buttonProgrami3"

        android:text="@string/programi_napredni"/>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:id="@+id/listaProgramiNapredni">
    </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here's Java file

```
 ListView listaProgramiPocetnici, listaProgramiSrednji, listaProgramiNapredni;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    int onStartCount = 0;

    Integer[] imageId = {R.drawable.ic_ikona_pocetnici,
            R.drawable.ic_ikona_pocetnici,
            R.drawable.ic_ikona_pocetnici,
            R.drawable.ic_ikona_pocetnici,
            R.drawable.ic_ikona_pocetnici,
            R.drawable.ic_ikona_pocetnici,
            R.drawable.ic_ikona_pocetnici,
            R.drawable.ic_ikona_pocetnici
            };

    Integer[] imageId2 = {R.drawable.ic_ikona_srednji,
            R.drawable.ic_ikona_srednji,
            R.drawable.ic_ikona_srednji,
            R.drawable.ic_ikona_srednji,
            R.drawable.ic_ikona_srednji,
            R.drawable.ic_ikona_srednji,
            R.drawable.ic_ikona_srednji,
            R.drawable.ic_ikona_srednji,
            R.drawable.ic_ikona_srednji,
            R.drawable.ic_ikona_srednji,
            R.drawable.ic_ikona_srednji,
            R.drawable.ic_ikona_srednji,
            R.drawable.ic_ikona_srednji,
            R.drawable.ic_ikona_srednji,
            R.drawable.ic_ikona_srednji};

    Integer[] imageId3 = {R.drawable.ic_ikona_napredni,
            R.drawable.ic_ikona_napredni};


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista_programi_bodybuilding);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        onStartCount = 1;
        if (savedInstanceState == null)
        {
            this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anim_slide_in_left,
                    R.anim.anim_slide_out_left);
        } else {
            onStartCount = 2;
        }


        AdapterListaVjezbe adapter = new AdapterListaVjezbe(ListaProgramiBodybuilding.this, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.programi_pocetnici), imageId);
        listaProgramiPocetnici = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listaProgramiPocetnici);
        listaProgramiPocetnici.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        listaProgramiPocetnici.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                if (position == 0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ListaProgramiBodybuilding.this, ProgramiBodybuildingTreningZaCijeloTijelo.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else if (position == 1) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ListaProgramiBodybuilding.this, ProgramiBodybuildingTreningZaGornjiDonjiDioTijela.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else if (position == 2) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ListaProgramiBodybuilding.this, ProgramiBodybuildingTreningKodKuceBezUtega.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else if (position == 3){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ListaProgramiBodybuilding.this, ProgramiTreningaTreningKodKuceBezUtega2.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else if (position == 4){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ListaProgramiBodybuilding.this, ProgramiTreningaTreningKodKuceBezUtega3.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else if (position == 5) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ListaProgramiBodybuilding.this, ProgramiBodybuildingTreningKodKucePocetnicki.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else if (position == 6) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ListaProgramiBodybuilding.this, ProgramiBodybuildingTreningKodKuceSrednji.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else if (position == 7) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ListaProgramiBodybuilding.this, ProgramiBodybuildingTreningKodKuceNapredni.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }


                    AdapterListaVjezbe adapter = new AdapterListaVjezbe(ListaProgramiBodybuilding.this, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.programi_srednje_napredni), imageId2);
                    listaProgramiSrednji = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listaProgramiSrednji);
                    listaProgramiSrednji.setAdapter(adapter);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    listaProgramiSrednji.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                            if (position == 0){
                                Intent intent = new Intent(ListaProgramiBodybuilding.this, ProgramiTreninga3dana.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                        } else if (position == 1){
                            Intent intent = new Intent(ListaProgramiBodybuilding.this, ProgramiTreninga4dana.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        } else if(position == 2){
                            Intent intent = new Intent(ListaProgramiBodybuilding.this, ProgramiTreninga5dana.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        } else if (position == 3) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(ListaProgramiBodybuilding.this, ProgramiBodybuilding3plus1.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        } else if (position == 4) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(ListaProgramiBodybuilding.this, ProgramiPowerBBPHAT.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        } else if (position == 5) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(ListaProgramiBodybuilding.this, ProgramiSpecijalizacijaPrsa.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        } else if (position == 6) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(ListaProgramiBodybuilding.this, ProgramiSpecijalizacijaLedja.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        } else if (position == 7) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(ListaProgramiBodybuilding.this, ProgramiSpecijalizacijaRamena.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        } else if (position == 8) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(ListaProgramiBodybuilding.this, ProgramiSpecijalizacijaRuke.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        } else if (position == 9) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(ListaProgramiBodybuilding.this, ProgramiSpecijalizacijaNoge.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            } else if(position == 10) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(ListaProgramiBodybuilding.this, ProgramiSpecijalizacijaZaTrbuh.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }else if (position == 11){
                                Intent intent = new Intent(ListaProgramiBodybuilding.this, ProgramiSpecijalizacijaZaListove.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            } else if (position == 12) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(ListaProgramiBodybuilding.this, ProgramiTreningaPushPullLegs.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            } else if (position == 13) { //UREDI
                                Intent intent = new Intent(ListaProgramiBodybuilding.this, ProgramiTreningaPushPullLegs.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            } else if (position == 14) { // UREDI
                                Intent intent = new Intent(ListaProgramiBodybuilding.this, ProgramiTreningaPushPullLegs.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }




                                AdapterListaVjezbe adapter = new AdapterListaVjezbe(ListaProgramiBodybuilding.this, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.programi_napredni), imageId3);
                                listaProgramiNapredni = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listaProgramiNapredni);
                                listaProgramiNapredni.setAdapter(adapter);
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                listaProgramiNapredni.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                                        if (position == 0) {
                                            Intent intent = new Intent(ListaProgramiBodybuilding.this, ProgramiKreacijaVlastitogMisicnaVlakna.class);
                                            startActivity(intent);
                                        } else if (position == 1) {
                                            Intent intent = new Intent(ListaProgramiBodybuilding.this, ProgramiKreacijaVlastitogPrimjeriTreninga.class);
                                            startActivity(intent);
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                        }});}});}
```

What did I miss there?
Tried to follow various tutorials on internet but none of them worked the way I want to.

Comment: Firstly, ListViews one after another is not the way to go. Better to design that differently. Secondly, you won't ever reach the other ListViews (depending how many items are in the first) because the entire set needs to be enveloped in a ScrollView to enable that.

Comment: I tried with scroll view but then it displays only one items from each list

Comment: In addition to Knossos' comments, `wrap_content` does not work well for `ListView` height. As does Knossos, I strongly encourage you to come up with a different GUI design, as this will be unusable on smaller phones. For example, you might go with three tabs, each having a `ListFragment`, where the tabs take the place of your buttons.

Comment: Why you don't try with gridview. also i would change the if else for switch

Comment: It isn't entirely obvious from your question, but if you intend to have extended options for advanced users... Perhaps you could have a setting in a Preference Activity that toggles that. Then you can populate a single list with all options that the user should see.

Comment: Why not use fragments so that one activity doesn't have to handle everything at once?

Comment: I don't like that tab look. I implemented search bar in action bar and used single list instead